# Simplifying a function defined by a triple integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Given the potential function:

$$\Phi(a,b,c) = \iiint\limits_{V} \frac {1}{\sqrt {(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2+(z-c)^2}}dx\ dy\ dz$$

for every $ (a,b,c) \notin V $ and  $V = \{(x,y,z)|\space R_1 \leq x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq  R_2 \}$

I need to calculate $\Phi(0,0,c)$ for $0 < c < R_1 $ and for $R_2 < c$.

I tried using spherical coordinates, but it only helps calculating $\Phi(0,0,0)$, which is $2\pi(R_2^2-R_1^2)$

if I'm not wrong, since the integral at $(0,0,c)$ becomes $$ \int_0^{2\pi}d\theta \int_0^{\pi}d\phi \int_{R_1}^{R_2} \frac {r^2 \cdot \sin\phi}{\sqrt{r^2-2c\cdot \cos\phi \cdot r + c^2}}dr$$ and I don't know how to solve it.

also, the result should be that the potential within all of the sphere $B((0,0,0),R_1)$ is constant.

I guess there's a simpler way to do it which I am missing (maybe another type of variable substitution? or using the second type of line integral $ \int\limits_{(0,0,0)}^{(0,0,c)}\nabla\phi \cdot dr $ ?
), so any idea will be helpful.

Comment: Did you try doing the $\phi$ integration *first*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

integrate with respect to $\phi$ first:

$\iiint \frac {r^2\sin\phi}{\sqrt{r^2-2cr\cos\phi + c^2}} \ d\phi\ dr\ d\theta\\
\iint \frac {r\sqrt{r^2-2cr\cos\phi + c^2}}{c}|_0^\pi \ dr\ d\theta\\
\iint \frac {r (|r+c| - |r-c|)}{c} \ dr\ d\theta$

If $c < R_1$ then $|r+c| - |r-c| = 2c$ over the interval $[R_1,R_2]$

if $c >R_2$ then $|r+c| - |r-c| = 2r$ over the inteval.

Comment: thank you very much, I thought that integrating with respect to $\phi$ first would also give a complicated integral but it didn't and it worked